# Core Data copy from one db to another in background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I have two database files where I can copy easily with core data from one context to another -- if I put both contexts in the main thread (`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`).
But how do I do it if I want it to happen asynchronously in a background thread where the contexts for each database file are `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`? Remember: Both contexts have different persistent store coordinators!
(PS: Since `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is deprecated in iOS 9 that confinement type is out of the question for me.)

Comment: Are you copying everything in the store, or just a subset?

Comment: @pbasdf: Only a subset.

Comment: Could you use a single context and PSC (merging the two models if they are different), add the two stores (using configurations if necessary), then use `affectedStores` to fetch from one and `allocateObject:toPersistentStore:` to insert on the other.  Just an idea; never tried it myself.

Comment: @pbasdf: Thanks. I didn't know that you could have multiple sqlite db persistors and have something like `affectedStores`. I even had the advantage that I only read from the source db so I didn't need allocateObject:. CoreData is smart enough to write to the correct db if only one is writable. Only important thing: Since the target db originated from the source db I had to regenerate the metadata uuid of the source db (open it one time before with separate NSPersistentStoreCoordinator in write mode, close it and reopen in read-only), otherwise it crashes with, like: Can't add same store twice.

Comment: @pbasdf: If you would repost your 2nd comment as answer I could mark it as the accepted answer.  PS: I found out: To change the metadata a read/write opening isn't needed, read-only works too.

Comment: Thanks; added as an answer.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single context and PSC (merging the two models if they are different).  Add the two stores (using configurations if necessary), then use `affectedStores` to fetch from one and `allocateObject:toPersistentStore:` to insert on the other.  If one store is opened read-only, then you will not need to use `allocateObject:`, Core-Data will infer the correct store to use.